# How to use JSON data from URL into table on my wordpress website

Tags: plugins, api, json

I want to display a data into table format on my wordpress website from the data available from below two JSON URL's

https://corona.lmao.ninja/all
https://corona.lmao.ninja/countries?sort={parameter} -- Here, we can replace the parameter from the data from 1st url.

API Details:
https://github.com/NovelCOVID/API

I am very new to this API & JSON thing, but if you will guide me with proper steps then I can implement that, as I am also a database developer. Coding will not be issue with me.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If you're trying to pipe this into maps and other things on the frontend, then you don't need WP knowledge or any WP code to handle it, just do the entire thing in javascript. **Otherwise it's not clear what you want to do with the data**, questions here need to be specific, as this is a Q&A site not a discussion forum. You need to state your question clearly, it needs to be self contained, and it needs to be answerable factually and concretely. Please use the edit link to modify your question and clarify what it is you're asking specifically

Comment: No.  I don't want to integrate those data into maps.  I just want to create simple table and want to display those data returning from JSON into tables on website.

Comment: You can do that in javascript too, request the data in JS, then instead of JSON decoding and passing to a map library, JSON decode it and construct a table instead. There's no reason for any of this to involve PHP or WordPress at all, it can be done with only javascript, and it would be faster too. Infact the API repo you linked to is written in javascript